# how to make the index and the value move together when sorting values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bubble-sort

I wrote this code in python language:

```
utilizArray = [0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.8] 
M = [] 
for i in range(len(utilizArray)): 
    M.append([i, utilizArray[i]]) 

print(M)
print() 

for passnum in range(len(utilizArray) - 1,0,-1): 
    for i in range(passnum): 
        if M[i][1] < M[i+1][1]: 
            temp = M[i][1] 
            M[i][1] = M[i+1][1] 
            M[i+1][1] = temp 
print() 
print(M)
```

Here is the output :

```
[[0, 0.7], [1, 0.6], [2, 0.4], [3, 0.3], [4, 0.8]]
[[0, 0.8], [1, 0.7], [2, 0.6], [3, 0.4], [4, 0.3]]
```

I want the output to be like this (every value with its corresponding index):

```
[[4, 0.8], [0, 0.7], [1, 0.6], [2, 0.4], [3, 0.3]]
```

could you please suggest me a code for that.

Answer (score 2):

You should compare based on the first element, but swap the entire element as a unit:

```py
utilizArray = [0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.8]
M = []
for i in range(len(utilizArray)):
    M.append([i, utilizArray[i]])

print(M)
print()

for passnum in range(len(utilizArray) - 1,0,-1):
    for i in range(passnum):
        if M[i][1] < M[i+1][1]:
            # the [1]s from these lines were removed
            temp = M[i]
            M[i] = M[i+1]
            M[i+1] = temp
print()
print(M)
```

Alternatively, just use the builtin `sort` function using the second element as a key (this method is also much faster than your bubble sort):

```py
utilizArray = [0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.8]
M = []
for i in range(len(utilizArray)):
    M.append([i, utilizArray[i]])

print(M)
print()

M.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print()
print(M)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get the index of the element of the list by using enumerate:

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for index, letter in enumerate(array):
    print(index, letter)

Output:
>0 a
>1 b
>2 c
```

Comment: As with the other answer, the first list is fine. The second is not. Please read the question, not just the title, when answering.